# Search for specific part of keyword in a file and return complete keyword

Tags: file, search, grep, keyword-search

I have a text file of format :

```
hello world line 1 1234567_45674345 new line this is hello world 
this is line 2 and new hello world 980765789_32345332
this is line 3 8976578_45345678 end of file
```

Now I have input number which is before underscore `1234567_45674345` for example in this case `1234567`

I need to search this number and return the complete word i.e. `1234567_45674345`

What I tried :
I used `grep` command but it returns complete line i.e. `hello world line 1 1234567_45674345 new line this is hello world`

What is the suitable way to do this ?
The file size is in order of `10MB`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -oP '1234567[^ ]+' inputFile
1234567_45674345
```

In case you have input number in a variable.

```
var=1234567
echo "$x" |grep -oP "$var[^ ]+"
1234567_45674345
```